# $\ker(A)=\text{Im}(A^*)^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

How do I show that $\ker(A)=\text{Im}(A^*)^\perp$ for any square matrix $A$.  I have done this problem before with the linear operator $T$ on a hermitian space but I can't seem to apply what I have done in that problem here.

Comment: Why are you having trouble applying what you've done?  A matrix $A$ is a linear operator from $\Bbb C^n$ to $\Bbb C^n$, and $\Bbb C^n$ under the usual inner product is certainly a Hermitian space.

Answer (score 6):

Let $x\in\ker A$ and $y\in \operatorname{im} A^*$ then there's $z$ such that $y=A^*z$ and then

$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*z\rangle=\langle Ax,z\rangle=\langle 0,z\rangle=0$$
so we proved that $\ker A\subset (\operatorname{im} A^*)^\perp$. Now let $x\in(\operatorname{im} A^*)^\perp$ so for every $y\in \operatorname{im} A^*$ we have
$0=\langle x,y\rangle$ so 
$$\forall z\in V,\quad 0=\langle x,A^*z\rangle=\langle Ax, z\rangle\implies Ax=0\implies x\in\ker A$$
and then we have $(\operatorname{im} A^*)^\perp\subset \ker A$. The equality follows by double inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let the rows of $A$ be denotes $A_i$. A vector $v$ is in the kernel if $A_i v = 0$ for all $i$, right?

Something is in the image of $A^{*}$ if it's a linear combination of the columns of $A^{*}$, which are the rows of $A$. So the image of $A^{*}$ consists exactly of values of expressions of the form
$$
\sum_i c_i A_i.
$$

If $w$ is perpendicular to all such expressions, then it's perpendicular to $A_1$ (by choosing $c_1 = 1, c_2 = 0, c_3 = 0, ...$) and similarly for all other $A_i$. In other words, the right hand side is contained in the left.

I think you can probably work out the rest from here; if not, just ask and I'll finish it up.